# How to save a plot as a B&W (no gray pixel) image in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating some test images which are supposed to have foreground and background colors only. I created my plots using `ggplot2`, and I saved them using the methods `jpeg()` and `png()`. But I realized that the output is not B&W. Below you can see a sample image and the issue as well.

[image: A sample image]

[*A sample image*]

[image: The image showing the issue]

[*Zoomed-in to show the none B&W output*]

How can I save a plot like that as a B&W image? (I prefer to stick to JPEG format.)

Comment: That looks like B&W to me. Do you want a higher resolution to reduce pixelation? Also you may not realise but `png` and `jpeg` functions are base R. You might want to use `ggsave` instead.

Comment: A B&W image should contain only black and white pixel regardless of the resolution (if smoothing is off in your image viewer). But I checked this by reading the image in Java, and that is how I am sure that there are gray pixels saved as well.

Comment: The smoothing is called [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing) and is applied by the device driver.  Note that a JPEG image might still have grey pixels because of lossy compression, even with anti-aliasing turned off.  Too avoid that, use PNG.

Comment: @david25272 great point. You are right, the `jpeg` method didn't work although I used `antialias = "none"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the option `antialias = "none"`. For example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
png(antialias = "none")
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:100, y=sin((1:100/10))), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line() 
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted. Let me ask you a side question: when I try to read this in Java, I see that the image type is TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED. Do you perhaps know how I can save it in R with a more conventional type, such as TYPE_BYTE_GRAY?